# Android .setText(TypeValue, float) not working

Tags: android, settext

this is how im implementing it

```
topBar.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, R.dimen.sTextSize);
```

this is the dimension

```
<item name="sTextSize" format="float" type="dimen">30.0</item>
```

the text size comes out to be very very very small, whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the ID as the text size, not the *value* stored under that ID. You should instead be doing something like this:

```
int textSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sTextSize);
topBar.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);
```

Comment: im getting a null pointer exception at ContextWrapper.getResources. on the line where im trying to instantiate                             float textSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sTextSize);

Comment: That code assumes you're calling `getResources()` from an appropriate Context (e.g. in onCreate()). If it's somewhere else, you'll need to pass in a `Context` and call `Context.getResources()`.